# Escape character for accolade during Json deserialize?

Tags: c#, .net, json, api

I try to deserialize a piece of Json (the Json was received from an api call).

I get the error 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '[0].state', line 1, position 516.'. The problem is that the state propery is a collection of properties and that there are accolades in it.
What can i do to acchieve the accolades are ignored?

Below is part of the original Json:

```
[{"id":220591,"title":"Revalidatie oefening 1.mp4","thumbnail":"https://xxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/content/68/5c5be74aacba4b3xxxxxxf731c2035.jpg","allowSharing":false,"autoPlay":false,"stream":false,"schedule":1893459661000,"lookback":1893546061000,"announce":true,"segment":"59db9f74fc204efcb154b2f352e77cae","segmentName":"Module Sport en Bewegen","name":"Revalidatie oefening 1.mp4","image":"https://xxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/content/68/xxxxxxxcba49f731c2035.jpg","published":false,"state":{"locked":false,"lockedBy":244},"webplayerUrl":"https://player.XXXXXX.nl/?code=9HikZKv9DfOypObg18C9oyrCC0JsL6SxRnDbIGg%2B680e2r%2FWv8YL%XXXXXX%2Bjw8bq90wx75q206LugsRpS%2FOUgf7%2BGEjYjvp5dnRO3z2uDktKd2%2BpmWWDaCD1yBwp4I8xVIQ89CZ9mxBFZ5dMF0y%  .. AND SO ON..
```

Comment: What are *accolades* ?

Comment: I mean this character: {

Comment: First, please make sure that you want to deserialize a valid json. You can use such online tool like [Json Formatter Online](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Answer given by a collegue: Just omit the problem property from the Json deserialize class and it will simply not be deserialized.

Comment: What is the *"problem property"* ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your string **IS NOT a valid JSON**. you can only deserialize a valid JSON.
So in your case:
1. Remove the **[** and **]** character manually, your string will become something like:

```
{
 "id":220591,
 "title":"Revalidatie oefening
1.mp4","thumbnail":"https://xxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/content/68/5c5be74aacba4b3xxxxxxf731c2035.jpg","allowSharing":false,"autoPlay":false,"stream":false,"schedule":1893459661000,"lookback":1893546061000,"announce":true,"segment":"59db9f74fc204efcb154b2f352e77cae","segmentName":"Module Sport en Bewegen","name":"Revalidatie oefening
1.mp4","image":"https://xxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/content/68/xxxxxxxcba49f731c2035.jpg","published":false}
```

=> Already a valid JSON.
2. You can deserialize that my many ways. For example using: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/